# Laravel pagination bootstrap broken?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have been trying to find a fix for this problem.

I have included `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;` in my `AppServiceProvider` and added `Paginator::useBootstrap();` in my `public function boot()`.

[image]

It comes out like the image above. Is anyone encountering this as well? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this post may be help for you: [Laravel 8 custom pagination example](https://devnote.in/laravel-8-custom-pagination-example/)

Answer (score 0):

`Paginator::useBootstrapFive();`

Use this bro, i found that on laravel doc

use `latest()->paginate()`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file.
Then add `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;` and find out the `boot()` function. Then write this line `Paginator::useBootstrap();` inside the function.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

are you using laravel/ui? if yes did you install the npm packages and compile them?

Comment: Hi Riyan! I am using tailwind but as I mentioned above I tried using bootstrap for it. I did run npm packages and compiled them too.